# Can't get Unity Mirror Networking example games to connect between my pc and android

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, firewall, unity3d-mirror

Mirror Networking has a lot of example scenes that show how to use it. I tried running two instances of one of their examples called Pong.
[Pong Example Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5L3HN.png)

It worked pretty well, however when I tried running it on two different devices (my pc and my smartphone) it didn't work. It actually worked for less than a second, but then the app stops suddenly. I tried disabling the firewall on Windows, but nothing changed.

This video below shows exactly the problem I am facing:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3qa4lFM7xo&feature=youtu.be
The IP address shown in the video (192.168.15.5) is the IP of my phone, which in that case is the host.